# Python - Can this code be made more efficient?

Tags: python-3.x, consolidation

Just wondering if there is a better/more efficient way to write this code. Very new and would just like to get different insight on code structure.

```
def fitness_club():
    gold_senior = 50
    gold = 60
    silver_senior = 30
    silver = 40
    age = input('Please enter your age: ')
    membership_plan = input('What type of membership would you like?\n1: Gold\n2: Silver\n')
    if int(age) < 65:
        if int(membership_plan) == 1:
            print('your plan cost will be $' + str(gold))
        else:
            print('your membership plan will cost $' + str(silver))
    else:
        if int(membership_plan) == 1:
            print('your plan cost will be $' + str(gold_senior))
        else:
            print('your membership plan will cost $' + str(silver_senior))


fitness_club()
```

Comment: Welcome; the only thing that stands out to me is that you could do the conversion to `int` at the time you read from input, like `int(input(...))` instead of writing `int(membership_plan)` multiple times. This is more of a question for https://codereview.stackexchange.com though.

Comment: Needs more error checking - what if I enter "-100" for my age, or "foo"? Or if I select plan "7"?

Comment: @kaya3 if I put ```int(input(...))``` it gives me the error "can't assign to function call". Also thank you for pointing me in the right direction when asking questions like this in the future!

Comment: Of course `int(input(...))` goes on the right hand side of the `=` sign, not on the left. Write it as `age = int(input('Please enter your age: '))`, for example.